# Can't initialize OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, sdl, sdl-2

I have some trouble to get my glew to work. When I initialize glew I get an error: Missing GL version. I can't create a context aswell: OpenGL not initialized.
This is my code:

```
#include <GL\glew.h>
#include <GL\GLU.h>
#include <SDL2\SDL.h>
#include <SDL2\SDL_opengl.h>

#include <iostream>
#undef main

SDL_GLContext context;
SDL_Renderer * renderer;
SDL_Window * window;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    //init SDL
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "\n> Unable to initialize SDL:  %s\n", SDL_GetError());
    }

    window = SDL_CreateWindow("Cri Engine 3D", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, 800, 600, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
    if (window == nullptr)
    {
        printf("> Window could not be created! SDL Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
    }

    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION, 3);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION, 1);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK, SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_CORE);

    context = SDL_GL_CreateContext(window);
    SDL_GL_MakeCurrent(window, context);


    if (context == NULL) {
        printf("> OpenGL context could not be created! SDL Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
    }

    //Glew
    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
    GLenum err = glewInit();
    if (GLEW_OK != err) {
        fprintf(stderr, "> Error: %s\n", glewGetErrorString(err));
    }
    fprintf(stdout, "> Using GLEW %s\n", glewGetString(GLEW_VERSION));

    glViewport(0, 0, 800, 600);

    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}
```

These are the linker settings I use(in this order): glew32.lib, glu32.lib, opengl32.lib, SDL2.lib, SDL2main.lib.

I'm sure that the libaries are correctly included. 
PS: this is my first post, if I am missing some information tell me!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're missing `SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL` flag for `SDL_CreateWindow()`.

Also, you *must* remove `#undef main`.
Otherwise you would need to do some low-level initialization yourself, which you don't do.

Another thing: You must switch to compatibility profile from core profile (`SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK, SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_COMPATIBILITY);`) because GLEW has a tendency to crash when you ask it to initialize a core profile context on Windows.

Also, many parts of your core are redundant:

- `SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN` - It is already used by default.
- `SDL_GL_MakeCurrent(window, context);` - Not needed when there is only one context.
- `glViewport(0, 0, 800, 600);` - When you create a context, it automatically sets up a correct viewport for you.
- `SDL_Quit();` - You don't need to call *anything* when your program ends. It does nothing but makes your program close slower. (At least this is how it works on Windows. On Linux it is sometimes necessary, as @keltar has pointed out. Also, it prevents leak detectors like valgring from yelling at you about SDL internal structures.)
- `#include <SDL2\SDL_opengl.h>` - It's a replacement for `<GL/gl.h>`, which you don't need because you already have `<GL\glew.h>`.

Comment: Thank you so much, I tried so long to get it to work. Adding the flag in SDL_CreateWindow() did the trick. I know the code is messy (because I have been messing with it for so long).

Comment: `SDL_Quit` part is quite arguable (e.g. valgrind); `SDL_opengl.h` is just wrong, it never gets included; it is kind of a replacement for `gl.h` though.

Comment: On the second thought, there is no `DestroyWindow`, so without `SDL_Quit` if window was fullscreen video mode wouldn't be restored (at least on X11), so it is even worse.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL` to window creation flags.